# Download or share view in Android

Tags: android, view, share

i have this view:

[image]

My question:

**I want to give the user the option to download or email this information. How can I do?**

The easiest way that I came up with is to do a sort of screen of the screen and send it. The problem is that the view goes far beyond the screen's why we have the scroll view.

Some Suggested ??

Comment: You could save the data to a text file (possibly a CSV) and send it. Or simply send out the text.

Comment: Ok thanks. is not possible to picture screen of display ?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's just more data to save and to send (an image is much heavier than pure text data).